# query_vars parameters

Tags: wordpress, parameters

I've a problem. I've tried a lot of things but I could not find a solution. I use query_vars parameters in this page and there isn't any problem. But i don't use different parameters or the same parameters in different custom page (../videolar). Parameter value is always empty. Parameters used once ?
Function.php :

```
function parameter($qvars){ 
 $qvars[] = 'kategori';
 $qvars[] = 'ara';
 $qvars[] = 'numara';
 $qvars[] = 'tur';
 return $qvars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'parameter');
```

videolar.php (../videolar?tur=test) :

```
global $wp_query;
echo $wp_query->query_vars['tur'] // empty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.

Re-save your permalink settings after you add the parameter. Or change the file permissions of .htaccess to 777.